# is there any gui for ELF file ( probably using readelf)?

Tags: gui

looking for a good gui for reading elf files. I know about readelf which is only command line

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://sourceforge.net/p/beye/wiki/Home/. It is a file viewer but has ELF displaying and navigating capabilities.